# Do the sliders in the Tactic Tweaker negatively effect the opposite effect?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

Confusing title, but not sure how best to word it.

Basically, in the Tactic Tweaker there are 2 setting areas that use sliders which allow you to prioritise one effect over another. The two areas are "Monster Affinities" and "Elements and Ailments".

My question is: if I move a slider towards one to get a boost, does it reduce the opposing effect?

For example, if I choose to boost damage to Solidity, will it negatively effect my damage to Sliminess?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the main purpose of the Tactic Tweaker.

It allows you to be stronger against X, but weaker against Y.

The only one without a downside is the battle one on the bottom right, which allows you to increase certain attributes. It's the most expensive one to level up because of this.